# A query with VB6 :but it display wrong sum

Tags: sql, vb6

I've write this cross query in Vb6 :

```
q = "TRANSFORM Count(Ans.Proc) AS ConteggioDiProc "
q = q & "SELECT Ans.Codice, Count(Ans.Proc) AS [Totale di Proc] From 
Ans GROUP BY Ans.Codice "
q = q & "PIVOT Format([Periodo],'mmm') In 
('gen','feb','mar','apr','mag','giu','lug','ago','set','ott','nov','dic');"
Data1.RecordSource = q
Data1.Refresh
```

Inside MS Access it's ok ( the total column is the sum of the months),but inside VB6 environment the numbers in the columns is wrong,is equal to the sum of every month ( i.e. the total)!

Here's inside access(this is correct):
[image]

Here's inside VB6:
[image]

Anyone can help me to solve this strange behavior inside VB6?

Comment: How are you connecting to Access from VB6? With ODBC? Or Something else. Version numbers might be important so try to add that info please.

Comment: I use DAO 3.6 .  tankyou

Answer (score 0):

maybe u need write like this .

```
select  sum(filed) as aa,...
```

and then read filed aa just like record set .